# Server 2008 R2 to Server 2016 options

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-10, windows-server-2016

I have a big problem. I have a 2008 R2 server which I've been asked to upgrade (for work) to 2016. I've found (through Microsoft) that it's not possible to do this 'in-place' (though if anyone knows different then please let me know!), or to migrate (as both servers need to be running, and there's only one box). I've backed up the `users` and `profiles` directories, which I'm guessing is where all the user data is held, but I don't know how to re-implement the base settings on the new server.

Is there a way to export / import settings and user data from one system to the other? My server experience is limited to Apache, and I'm in way over my head on this one, so any help at all will be greatfully received.

Secondly (sorry!). The boxes that connect to the current server are all running XP, and we have bought in a load of new Win10 boxes, but they are all Home Edition. I know that in the past there was the `http://server-name/connect` option for non Pro type OS's, is this still the case with 2016 of do we need to volume license for Pro?

Could the 2008 `connect` to the Win10 Home? The main reason for the upgrade is to lose the XP machines, so if we could connect the new machines to the existing server it would work for me...

Sorry about all the questions, but I'm a software guy and I'm panicking here. I'm the only IT guy on the ground and it's fallen in my lap to sort this out.

Thanks in advance...

Danny

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yeah you are pretty much screwed,

My advice, use windows backup on the server, take a full backup and save to a NAS of other external HDD, make sure to do both a file level and image level backup, install server 2016 setup the server get all the features and roles setup, and then transfer the files over.

That should take care of the server, if you cannot tolerate any downtime you will have to do this on a weekend or at night when you can, and explain that unfortunately down time is needed.

As for the Win 10 Home, I ran into a similar situation before, I tried everything I could think of to get the on the DC but had to get the proper license,

I know its probably not the most helpful but i did read a couple articles on line that had some really hacky ways of migrating Server 2008 R2 to 2016

Google: Migrate Server 2008 R2 to Server 2016

Most of the time I have found the hacky way to be a temporary solution and it should be done correctly to eliminate putting out fires you have no idea how they got started.

Comment: Thanks Anthony, must be something about this job, I tend to get screwed quite a lot... I only came in to maintain the websites!
I have actually searched that exact phrase, and found some real doozies. Depends how desparate I get, but might well give them a go. If I break it, it's not going to get any more broken by hacking on it. Cheers.

I'll leave it open a while longer, but I'm pretty sure yours in going to be correct.

Comment: @allnodcoms Make sure you do the backups